# @CreationTimestamp with value from DB is excessive?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any reason to add annotation

```
@CreationTimestamp(source = SourceType.DB)
```

instead of

```
@Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
```

except for db schema-generation?
Anyway value will be set by DB.

Moreover, `CreationTimestamp` is not compartible with `Immutable`, and cause error `JpaSystemException: Lock mode not supported`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bit differences in term of the generated insert SQL and the configuration of the create timestamp column.

`@Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)` requires you to configure the DB column to have a default value which is set to the current timestamp. The generate SQL will not include the created time column because of `insertable=false`

`@CreationTimestamp(source = SourceType.DB)` does not require the DB column to have such default value setting. Hibernate will call the current timestamp fucntion from DB, and use its value to generate the insert SQL.